# How should I embed a paragraph in a Symfony2 form?

Tags: forms, symfony

I use the Symfony2 form component to create a registration form and I just want to add a paragraph saying the user must understand terms of service above the submit button.

Should I create a ParagraphType and use it in the controller or override the submit button's block and add the paragraph in the template?

Neither of these suits me. Is there a better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I would just add this text right before the submit button block in the template.

Comment: I really don't want to add each field in my view since I can use the `form()` function. But maybe will I be forced?

Comment: Why not add a [checkbox](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/checkbox.html) with the label "I understand the terms of service"?

Comment: @sjagr great workaround, I'll ask the designer!

Comment: Awesome - I've converted my comment into a more detailed answer if you think it helped the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without breaking the form into separate fields using `form_widget` for each field so you can inject a paragraph between the later part of the form and the submit button, you are restricted to using only form elements, meaning you can either create a special Form Type or use a form element. So under that logic, you can just make the "I understand the terms of service" a part of the form itself!

```
$builder->add('tos', 'checkbox', array(
    'label'     => 'I agree with the Terms of Service',
    'required'  => true,
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix, just don't add submit button as field of form and manually render it in view. This way, you can add also some paragraph before it.

Comment: Now that Symfony2 supports buttons in form it somewhat buggers me... Thanks anyway!